# Можно ли описывать предмет действия в деепричастном обороте до самого действия?

Tags: стилистика, деепричастный-оборот

Например:

1. Он пошёл по дороге и, подняв мусор, выкинул его в контейнер.
2. Она села на стул и, достав ручку, бросила её в окно.
3. Они ворвались в комнату и, сбросив с кровати одеяло, принялись его топтать.

Правильно ли это стилистически?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А какую запись вы предполагаете корректной? "Он пошёл по дороге и выкинул в контейнер мусор, подняв его"? Но ведь это очевидная ошибка порядка действий, потому что сперва мусор был поднят, а потом выкинут.

[Розенталь](http://rozental.gramatik.ru/xlviii-parallelnye-sintaksicheskie-konstrukcii/ss-212-deeprichastnye-oboroty):

> Деепричастный оборот обычно предшествует сказуемому, если обозначает:
> а) предшествующее действие, например: Оттолкнув меня, бабушка
> бросилась к двери… (Горький); б) причину другого действия, например:
> Испугавшись неведомого шума, стая тяжело поднялась над водой (А.
> Первенцев); в) условие другого действия, например: Напрягши силы,
> человек самых средних способностей может добиться чего угодно (В.
> Панова).

У вас во всех случаях деепричастный оборот совершенно правильно предшествует второму однородному сказуемому.

Comment: @Инга, меня интересует не изменение предложений на другие варианты, а вопрос стилистических ошибок. Ваши примеры из справочника совсем другие.

Comment: @Theej в ваших примерах стилистических ошибок нет.

Comment: @Инга спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Если деепричастие несовершенное, то оборот или одиночное деепричастие может находится как перед сказуемым, так и после — ‟Он шёл домой, думая о завтрашнем дне” и ‟Думая о завтрашнем дне, он шёл домой”; если деепричастие совершённое, то оборот также может находится перед и после сказуемого — ‟Выполнив работу, он пошёл домой” и ‟Он пошёл домой, выполнив работу”. Всё ваше недоумение связано с тем, что в ваших предложениях деепричастие и глагол-сказуемое направлены на один и тот же объект, который обозначаются существительным и местоимением, и если деепричастие переставить после сказуемого, то нужно также поменять местами существительное и местоимение. Если местоимение идет перед существительным, то непонятно, на что указывает местоимение. Если есть предложение: ‟Выполнив работу, он сохранил её на жёстком диске”, то это предложение можно переделать в: ‟Он сохранил работу на жёсткий диск, выполнив её”. После такого переделывания всё в порядке. Я имею ввиду, что если есть предложение: ‟Он шёл и, подняв мусор, выбросил его”, то его нельзя заменить на предложение: ‟Он шёл и выбросил его, подняв мусор”, потому что не понятно, что обозначается местоимением ‟его”; тут нужно также поменять местами существительное и местоимение — ‟Он шёл и выбросил мусор, подняв его”.

Но всё ещё после этих преобразований в предложениях: ‟Он шёл по дороге и выкинул мусор в контейнер, подняв его”, ‟Она села на стул и бросила ручку в окно, достав её — есть что-то неправильное.

Если предложение просто повествует о двух последовательных действиях и мы хотим поставить деепричастный оборот после сказуемого (речь идет о совершённом деепричастии и направленности двух действий на один и тот же объект, как в ваших примерах), то нужно добавить слово ‟предварительно”. Вот несколько примеров: ‟Он шёл по дороге и выкинул мусор в контейнер, предварительно подняв его”, ‟Она села на стул и бросила ручку в окно, предварительно достав её. Но слово ‟предварительно” не нужно добавлять тогда, когда совершённый деепричастный оборот после сказуемого имеет причинное значение. Вот несколько примеров: ‟Я продал акции, убедившись в их бесполезности”, ‟Он сохранил работу на жёсткий диск, закончив её”, ‟Я бросил работу, устав от неё”.

Comment: Так в этих примерах местоимение не стоит перед существительным.

Comment: И все же у меня немного другие предложения. Ваши примеры выглядят абсолютно нормально и стандартно.

Comment: @oleedd, я имею ввиду, что если есть предложение: ‟Он шёл и, подняв мусор, выбросил его”, то его нельзя заменить на предложение: ‟Он шёл и выбросил его, подняв мусов”, потому что не понятно, что обозначается местоимением ‟его”; тут нужно также поменять местами существительное и местоимение — ‟Он шёл и выбросил мусор, подняв его”.

Comment: @Theej , да, что-то всё ещё остаётся неправильным. Может быть, потом допишу ответ.

Comment: @Theej, Я всё понял и дополнил ответ.

Comment: @JimKorbett Ну я понял, но смысл об этом говорить, если в предложениях такого нет? Всем известно, что сначала используется существительное, а потом местоимение, чтобы не было тавтологии.

Comment: Первый пример нормален, а эти нет: *Он сохранил работу на жёсткий диск, закончив её. Я бросил работу, устав от неё.* Не звучит. Проблемы со стилистикой.

Comment: На мой взгляд, с примерами всё в порядке. Пользователь Thee назвал пример про сохранение работы на жёсткий диск абсолютно нормальным. Могу ещё набросать. Он начал бинтовать ногу, поранив её. Я выгнал сотрудника, застав его за онанизмом на рабочем месте. Я выбросил посылку, не увидев в ней того, что заказывал.

Comment: Про ногу — просто ужасно. Следующие чуть лучше, но нет, не считаю их корректными (очень разговорно). У Розенталя есть тема об употреблении деепричастий. Есть там такое? Ещё и стилистику надо учитывать: скажут так люди или это притянуто за уши.